# Why does $(this) work differently depending on how callback is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display a table and cause certain actions to take place if the user clicks on a cell in the table.  My Javascript (using jquery-3.1.1.min) looks like this:

```
    $(function() { 

      function tdHeader(key) {
          return '<td class="mytable-cell" data-key="' + key + '">';
      }

      function clickHandler() {
          alert("Key: " + $(this).data("key"));
      }

      function displayTable() {
          var tabHTML = '<table class="mmmtab">';
          tabHTML += '<tr><th>Data1</th><th>Data2</th><th>Data3</th></tr>';
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              tabHTML += '<tr>';
              for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                 key = i + "-" + j;
                 tabHTML += tdHeader(key) + ((i + 1) * (j + 1)) + '</td>';
              }
              tabHTML += '</tr>';
          }
          tabHTML += '</table>';
          $("#mytable").html(tabHTML);
          $(".mytable-cell").click(clickHandler);                 // Version 1
//        $(".mytable-cell").click(function() {clickHandler();}); // Version 2
      }

      displayTable();
    });
```

What I'm finding is that if I use Version 1 to set up the callback, then if I click on a cell, the alert box displays the correct key.  However, if I use Version 2, the alert box says "Key: undefined".

What's going on, and why does it make a difference which callback I use?

[Assuming I need the Version 2 because I want to pass some local data to the handler, I can solve my problem by passing `$(this).data("key")` as a parameter to the handler.  But I'd still like to know why it's doing this.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery .on will change 'this' automatically for your event callback.
In version 1, 'this' in clickHandler will be $(".mytable-cell").
But in version 2, 'this' is window. (Because your event callback calls clickHandler, clickHandler makes a new context)

please try:

```
$(".mytable-cell").click(function() {clickHandler.bind(this)();});
```

Comment: This will call the `clickHandler` in the correct context, but will not pass through the arguments that are passed to the event callback.  So you cannot access the `event` object in the `clickHandler`. And I wouldn't use bind in that case, normaly you use `bind` only if you want bind a certain context to a function for later use (e.g.  `$(".mytable-cell").click(obj.foo.bind(obj))` ), and `call` and `apply` if you want to change the context for the current call @ajb

Answer (score 4):

jQuery calls the callback you pass to `click` in the context of the element the event belongs to. So for `$(".mytable-cell").click(clickHandler);` the `clickHandler` is called in the context of the given DOM element.

For `$(".mytable-cell").click(function() {clickHandler();});` the anonymous function is called in the context of the DOM element and inside of this you call `clickHandler` in the context of `undefined` or the global object.

You would need to write `$(".mytable-cell").click(function() {  return clickHandler.apply(this, arguments); } );` if you want that the behavior is the same.

Comment: I've found that using `.call` instead of `.apply` also works, where the difference is that `.apply()` needs two arguments with the second one being an array of arguments, while `.call` accepts any number of arguments.